# PHP/MYSQL converting unsigned int to signed int

Tags: php, mysql, int, signed

in mysql:

```
select CAST(17640478426339470149 as SIGNED INTEGER); #-806265647370081467
```

in php:

```
echo sprintf("%d", 17640478426339470149); #-806265647370082304
```

how I will get same signed int ? (and why this difference occurs?)

Comment: check integer size and hence upper/lower limits.

Comment: On my 32bit x86 Windows XP with WAMP I get `0` for PHP(4 octet integer) and MySQL seems to use 8 octet integer.

Comment: Try `var_dump(17640478426339470149)` it its probably a double instead of an int. That would explain the error in the last digits.

Comment: guys, thanks for explanation, there is some overflow in PHP, but the question still remains unanswered even it got minus 1 point.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution, I am not sure, if it is optimal one, but at least it works.

```
echo gmp_strval(gmp_com(gmp_xor('17640478426339470149', '0xffffffffffffffff')));
#-806265647370081467
```